# Creating a margin for html page with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a margin on the left-hand side on my html page. I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

Inside my html header, I have these lines;

```
    <script src="misc/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="misc/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="owncss/own.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Inside `own.css`, I have these lines;

```
body {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Unfortunately, on the webpage, there is zero margin. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try to use `!important` on your styles

Comment: @Suresh: May I know how do I use it in my case?

Comment: margin-left: 20px !important;

Comment: add this type="text/css" to <link type="text/css" href="owncss/own.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: yunandtidus and Sathish: I tried both your methods. Did not work. I discovered that some some reason, bootstrap.min.css is forcing the margin-left to 0. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Sathish is correct, make sure your stylesheet is linked.
Bootply to verify that your style, when linked correctly, will set a margin of 20px:
http://www.bootply.com/DC0e2nPVPL